How do I fix Power Automate Create Item Error
I'm having trouble with my workflow copying the data to a sharepoint list due to the following error message:
"The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Create_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'item/field_13' is required to be of type 'Number/double'. The runtime value '""' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'Number/double'."

I'm not really sure on how to identify which field on the sharepoint list it is referring to as it is not named.

I tried to change all of the number fields on my sharepoint list to single line of text and that did not work.

I've tried the if(empty) in all of my date fields and that did not work as well.


I'm stuck and have run out of resources.  Any help would be appreciated.

Go to a browser and access your SharePoint site where the list resides.
Now navigate to this URL in the browser itself (obviously replacing the relevant parameters with your own information) ...
https://<your_tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<yoursite>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<your_list_name>')/fields

... and then throw the result in VS Code or some other XML formatting tool and then search for field_13, that should tell you.
There are other ways but that's pretty easy.

Thanks for your response! I'm new to this would you happen to have a source I could use to show me the steps of how to do this?

Well … not really, I’ve just laid out the steps for you.

you can find easily your lost field, if you know in which list is it:

open the list

Open the list settings (upper right corner, the 'cog wheel' icon, then 'List settings'), which should be like this:
https://{YOUR TENANT}/sites/{YOUR SITE}/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=%7{GUID OF YOUR LIST}%7D

you need to put this string to the end of this url:
&Field=field_13


If you found it, and you can't modify the input value, you should add a multiply function to the 'Create item' field: just multiply your original value with '1'.
For example, if your original step was this:
@{triggerBody()?['ID']}

then change it to this:
@{mul(triggerBody()?['ID'],1)}

